# Dynamically Generating Javascript Instructions Through PHP with Magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento

### Goal

I would like to be able to dynamically create javascript and serve it based on preset configuration from the application. The url of the javascript resource can remain the same. The idea is to make available the option to change javascript parameters depening on backend configuration.

An example of this:

The administrator has a set of classes that when clicked upon open a modal pane for the end user. lets say that those classes follow the format of *_modal where the * portion of the class will indicate a portion of the url where the content of the modal pane will be pulled from via ajax.

For example:

click me

would then trigger an ajax event on click where the contents from #contents would be pulled from http://www.myurl.com/modal/orange and displayed in the div #modal_output at the client side.

lets say for some odd reason the administrator for the site decided that he wanted to change the id of the display modal pane for some reason to #modal_output_view . Normally this would require some modification of the javascript and possibly the static output of the page.

I would like to forgo that and offer a configuration option whereas the administrator can choose what the div id would be for the modal output.

At run-time the resource would be requested, php would grab the configuration value for that div's id and return a string in the form of a javascript resource.

Secondly I will be using magento, is there a good way to improve the performance via cache?
Is there any way to use a cdn?

### Questions

1) I know how to do the configurational portion, asside from doing this within an appended block or inside of a template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
 configuration_value = <?= Mage::getStoreConfig('my/config/value');?>;
})();
</script>
```

is there another easier way to interface between magento's configuration values and client side javascript?

2) Will this work correctly? are there any issues I might face? The key being the .php extension

3) Are there existing core javascript classes/methods that may be useful? Any documentation?

Comment: I have no idea what's being asked here — other than "please build my thing for me"

Comment: Lets make this clear, there probably is no need for any code to be shown here. I am asking how to insert data derived from php calls through a magento framework to populate data within a hypothetical javascript method or function for use client side. Alan, being that your comment was nonconstructive (unexpectedly) I would like to appoligize for your bad day and invite you to explain in your own words a better way to ask this question so as to learn from the master ( whole heatedly i respect you as a developer).

Comment: Break your problem into smaller parts and ask specific questions about implementing those smaller parts.